# What triggers cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a TableView that I am trying to load data into. From the `NSLog` displays the data is correct and present. However the following method isn't being called, e.g. the `NSLog` comments are not appearing at all.:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
}
NSString *cellValue = [listOfStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
return cell; 
NSLog(@"Passed: cellForRowAtIndexPath");
```

}

Similarly the init isn't being run either. I though init was always run, if present?

```
- (id)init { 
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    listOfStates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    stateName = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"INIT StateName %@", stateName);
    }
return self;
 NSLog(@"Passed: init");
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called by the table view on its data source when a cell is needed, this can be either when a cell is first shown, or when the user is scrolling and the cell will appear

your init method is not being called because UITableView uses `initWithFrame:style:` and UITableViewController (it wasnt clear which init you are trying to override) uses `initWithStyle:`, not the "plain" init method. If you want to do custom setup you should override these methods

and as the other answers have mentioned, anything you put after a return statement will never be executed

Comment: Many thanks for your wisdom. Neither initWithFrame or initWithSTyle appear to being activated???

For the datasource so I need to put cell.pickerDelegate = self; into the cellForRowAtIndexPath? I'm always used, so far, to dealing with the datasources from the StoryBaord.

And thanks for kicking me about the return order :-)

Comment: which class's init method are you overriding? pickerDelegate is something completely different, but you do need to set the dataSource of the tableView to be an object (if you use a UITableViewController this is done for you, the data source is the controller)

Comment: The DataSource and the Delegate are linked to the TableView.

Answer (score 1):

If you put `NSLog` after return ,it would exit the method and NSLog would not be called, whenever you call return it exits that method.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called as a datasource method from your table view. To get it called you have to set the tableviews datasource property to the class which implements `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. On the other hand sujith is right: `NSLog` will not be called after a `return`.

Comment: Actually you have to set the datasource property correctly for that method to be called. Guess you ment that :)

Comment: As above am naive as to how to specify the DataSource in this method. Can you spell it out for me as normally do it via the StoryBoard. Many thanks.

Comment: Resolved - the DS was pointing correctly, it was a prefixing issue. Very many thanks for everyone's help.